# ETL vs ELT in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl, talend

We are researching on creating a Data Lake solution on AWS - similar to what's outlined here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/introducing-the-data-lake-solution-on-aws/

We will be storing all the "raw" data in S3 and load it into EMR or Redshift as needed.

At this stage, I am looking for suggestions on whether to use the ETL or the ELT approach for loading data into Amazon Redshift. We will be using Talend for ETL/ELT.

Should we stage the "raw" data from S3 in Redshift first before transforming it or should we transform the data in S3 and load it into Redshift?

I would appreciate any suggestion/advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely ELT.

The only case where ETL *may* be better is if you are simply taking one pass over your raw data, then using COPY to load it into Redshift, and then doing nothing transformational with it. Even then, because you'll be shifting data in and out of S3, I doubt this use case will be faster.

As soon as you need to filter, join, and otherwise transform information, it is much faster to do it in the DBMS. If you hit a case where the data transformation relies on data that is already in the DW, it will be orders of magnitude faster.

We run hundreds of ELT jobs a day on different DW platforms, performance testing alternative methods of ingesting and transforming data. In our experience the difference between ETL and ELT in an MPP DW can be 2000+ percent.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the purpose of having Redshift. If your business case is for users to query the data against Redshift (or a front end application using Redshift as backend), then i would not recommend to do ETL in Redshift. In this case, it would be better to perform your business transformations ahead of time (ex: S3->EMR->S3) and then load the processed data to Redshift.